# Solution Layers architecture for big enterprises in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, architecture, solution

I need to get a very clear idea about how to divide my solution folders and projects in the visual studio.
this should serve as will the big enterprise solutions too.
I need to have an idea about every project and folder what its content and what it's for?

for example, this architecture is it fit the big enterprise and I will not need to change the architecture. matter what the business becomes bigger and bigger?

[image]

what is the best practice architecture can be?

Comment: I think this structure would be sufficient enough.